# OpenVPN client source port keeps changing, TLS fails

Tags: networking, openvpn, nat

This problem only happens behind certain routers/gateways and i have no control over. this is my clients connecting over public internet. what seems to be the problem is that the source PORT changes almost instantaneously. and yes this is only specific to certain devices for example **fortigate** devices when they are the gateway. and yes i ruled out the devices, my gateway, my server, everything. since when they try over Cellular it works immediately. i don't know what's wrong with these gateways and why do they do that.

Also, could it be an issue when there is asymmetric wan routing taking place ?

i'm using TCP and NOT UDP. i tried UDP and still the same.

> Tue Mar 12 00:11:47 2021 X.X.X.X:47804 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]X.X.X.X:47804, sid=(bla bla bla )

> Tue Mar 12 00:11:49 2021 X.X.X.X:47807 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]X.X.X.X:47807, sid=(WHATEVER)

> Tue Mar 12 00:11:51 2021 X.X.X.X:478XX TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]X.X.X.X:478XX, sid=(WHATEVER)

and it keeps on and on ( TLS failed and Client instance restarting ) and XX keeps incrementing

is there any way to "POKE" a NAT port open till the client finishes the negotiation ? i set Keep-alive to 1 second which is the bare minimum i think and still

thanks in advance, i'm losing my mind over this

EDIT :

someone also seems to have that exact problem [HERE IS A SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug54v.png)

Comment: Yes, it could be caused by asymmetric wan routing. What's in the client log?

Comment: Two seconds difference suggest that the initial TCP handshake fails and the client is trying a second and a third connection. Can you take a packet capture at the server to verify this?

Comment: @MathiasWeidner
the client never receives the opposite packet. i can show you a screenshot on android. ( received packets = 0 , sent packets >0 and keeps on climbing. while on the server it replies to the same port..

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov 

just hangs on Authenticating.. keeps on sending packets and the ( recevied packets ) is zero, never increases

Comment: This is very strange. Could you please show more info, on how network on the server is configured and how it reaches an internet. Where affected clients are from (geographically)? If replies seem to be sent on the server but don't get received by the client, it could be that some deep inspection is going in the middle and it detects OpenVPN and drops it forcefully.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov yes i suspect that also. i'm running OpenVPN on port 443 and TCP, i thought that it'd pass any firewall like any HTTPS traffic and remain under the radar..  **PS** check the updated screenshot that i posted

server is running on an OpenWrt router and added to DMZ on the modem. **no** port translation takes place. i have access to the router's NAT table and traffic is directly forwarded to the server ( other router ). also verified using Tcpdumps. soo server side is fully functioning. and by the way in can connect from 98% of the networks 

ONLY fortigate has that problem

Comment: Then that's fortigate is a thing that does some DPI by default, that simple. Probably it monitors a port 443 and expects HTTPS protocol there, but when it sees something unexpected it drops that for security. Or even fortigate tries to do ssl bumping, I don't know. Anyways, OpenVPN doesn't do HTTPS protocol even if running on port 443, it always runs its own protocol, and it's easy to find out this is not HTTPS.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov hmmm never knew that.. i thought it was disabled by default. 
and i didn't even know it tries to intercept HTTPS traffic and verify it or literally MITM it. isn't that invading privacy ? 

also can you suggest another port ? i tried TCP 53 and it didn't work at all i don't know why. i want it immune to locked down network and networks that run ACLs

also check the screenshot i updated the post. apparently someone has that exact problem

Comment: A skillful admin could disable any unwanted traffic, if they need. Especially if that is company security policy to deep inspect traffic, and admins get paid for exactly that. My opinion that's not invanding privacy. The corporate internet is for work, not for some suspicious VPNs, don't you think? If this VPN is for work, user could go to admin and explain them and they would permit it, but then why hiding at HTTPS port?
What to do? Try running a service on several ports (1194), configure several connection profiles in client configs (multiple `remote` lines at least), hope some would work.

Comment: Agred, I wouldn't use port 443 for OpenVPN. Try using its default port, or some random high port number.

Answer (score 0):

You have no problem with the VPN, your problem is with the TCP connection that is probably restricted by the Fortigate firewall (**fortigate** device) you mentioned.

The way to solve this is to talk to the administrator of the firewall and ask for permission to contact the VPN server.

Comment: it isn't a workplace, they are literally public networks ! 

sometimes public networks put fortigate to block large downloads and "bandwidth consuming sites" just wanted to clarify that it is **not** Work internet or something like that. i just wanted to fix it so that a road warrior can connect to the network. nothing serious. sooo i can't talk to anyone. that's why i thought there is a method to make it work

Comment: If someone goes so far to block large downloads, this would be the one to talk to. If you just want to overcome the block for yourself, try different ports or UDP and set up your VPN server accordingly.

Comment: Hear this..! This is the latest updates. So I made 3 instances on ports 80, 53, 8080. I  went to a place which I know uses fortigate and I have that issue there. NONE of them worked... on the server the packets never made it...how on earth does fortigate monitor port 53 and blocks connections. ..is that even by default ?